# Logic for creating nested lists

Tags: c#, html, logic, nested-lists

I'm interpreting a text file with nested lists in the following format

```
- todo
  - clean kitchen
    - do dishes
    - sweep floor
  - cook dinner
    - defrost fish
  - shopping
    - milk
    - eggs
```

I want to place these items into <ul></ul> list. I'm trying to work out the logic of doing this, and at the moment its a horrible mess of calculating the "depth" via the number of spaces and adding opening or closing `ul` tags depending on whether the last depth was higher or lower.

There must be a smart, neat logic to doing this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy enough to determine the level by using `string.IndexOf`:

```
string line = file.ReadLine();
int level = line.IndexOf('-');
level = (level - 1)/2;
```

The logic to handle the levels is a little more interesting. Something like the following should work well.

```
int lastLevel = -1;
string line;
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    int level = GetLevel(line); // from code above
    int diff = level - lastLevel;
    if (diff > 1)
    {
        // skipping multiple levels forward is probably an error.
        throw new ApplicationException();
    }
    if (diff == 1)
    {
        // next level. Add a <ul>
        WriteUl();
    }
    else if (diff == 0)
    {
        // same level. Add an <li>
        WriteLi(line);
    }
    else
    {
        // need to add </ul>, possibly multiple times
        do
        {
            WriteUlEnd();
            --lastLevel;
        } while (lastLevel > level);
    }
    lastLevel = level;
}
```

If all you have is the data you show, that's really the only way to do it. You'll have to count the spaces.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I was hoping for a way around doing this though. For one thing, it limits me to a finite number of levels (which maybe I should be). I might actually go a totally different way and use divs instead of unordered lists, and just add a class which indents them a certain amount

Comment: I don't see the problem with having a finite number of levels. In this case, "finite" means something over 2 billion. And if you really wanted to get big, you could use a `long`. And, yeah ... you could do it with `div`. It would simplify the logic somewhat, 'cause you wouldn't have to worry about nesting.

Comment: Ah, I misread the code slightly, though it only catered to a single depth level, and I'd have to add more if statements. thanks